# Why I cannot use std::find when the basic element in a container is a boost::tuple?

Tags: c++, boost

I give the following codes to make my question more clear:

```
    bool bFind;
    boost::tuple<int> abc;
    //int abc;
    std::vector<boost::tuple<int> > myArray;
    //std::vector<int> myArray;
    bFind = is_vector_contains(myArray,abc);
```

is_vector_contains is template function:

```
template<typename T>
    bool is_vector_contains(const std::vector<T> &vecArray, const T &element)
    {
        if(std::find(vecArray.begin(),vecArray.end(),element) == vecArray.end())
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

When I compile the above codes, I have the following compilation error:

```
Error   1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const boost::tuples::tuple<T0>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Any ideas? I tried to define a equal operator in this way, but it did not succeed in compilation.

```
 bool operator == (const boost::tuple<int> &a, const boost::tuple<int> &b)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: So, what did you try to understand this? Did you check the docu of `boost::tuple`? (Incidently, I find your function name `is_vector_contains()` rather strange).

Comment: @Waller Thanks, and as you suggested I read the documentation and found the same answer as the one  in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::tuple`'s comparison operators are defined in a separate header, which you must include:

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>
```

Comment: This appears correct, but why? What is the motivation behind that? To allow the user to define the comparisons in a different way (that's going to ask for trouble)? Boost keeps perplexing me.

Comment: @Walter I have no idea. I also find it annoying, but fortunately it is super-trivial to search for.

Comment: @Walter @ juanchopanza In fact in my case I did not know that I should include another head file to make comparison possible. I indeed implement the equal operator, but it did not work. I will  my question to make it clear.